# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for 'conv3d_1/convolution' (op: 'Conv3D') with input shapes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I m trying to train a data on a 3dcnn I used the code bellow :

```
# image specification
img_rows,img_cols,img_depth=16,16,15
# CNN Training parameters

batch_size = 2
nb_classes = 6
nb_epoch =50

# number of convolutional filters to use at each layer
nb_filters = [32, 32]

# level of pooling to perform at each layer (POOL x POOL)
nb_pool = [3, 3]

# level of convolution to perform at each layer (CONV x CONV)
nb_conv = [5,5]
```

## Define model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution3D(nb_filters[0],nb_conv[0], nb_conv[0],nb_conv[0], input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols, patch_size), activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0])))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, init='normal', activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(nb_classes,init='normal'))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop')
```

and whan I run it I got this error

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for 'conv3d_1/convolution' (op: 'Conv3D') with input shapes: [?,1,16,16,15], [5,5,5,15,32].
```

can someone suggest me a solution please!

Answer (score 0):

There is problems in the structure of the model. Please add the code marked by blue and think about problems in code marked by red: [image]

...the full code is here for further processing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution3D,MaxPooling3D,Dropout,Flatten,Dense,Activation

# image specification
img_rows,img_cols,img_depth=16,16,15
# CNN Training parameters

batch_size = 2
nb_classes = 6
nb_epoch =50

# number of convolutional filters to use at each layer
nb_filters = [32, 32]

# level of pooling to perform at each layer (POOL x POOL)
nb_pool = [3, 3]

# level of convolution to perform at each layer (CONV x CONV)
nb_conv = [5,5]

#Define also the size of kernel...
kernel_size_definition=(3,3,3)

model = Sequential()
#model.add(Convolution3D(nb_filters[0],nb_conv[0], nb_conv[0],nb_conv[0], input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols, patch_size), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution3D(nb_filters[0],kernel_size=kernel_size_definition, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_depth,1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0])))

#Add the second layer, too...?

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())

#model.add(Dense(128, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#model.add(Dense(nb_classes,init='normal'))

#model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.add(Dense(nb_classes))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop')

#Let's probe the model...
test_input=tf.ones((1,img_rows, img_cols, img_depth,1))

#with a input of shape...
print(test_input.shape)

test_result=model(test_input)

#And see the corresponding output...
print(test_result.shape)
```

Comment: I change it but I got this error ,when I want to rain it:ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_4_input to have shape (16, 16, 15, 1) but got array with shape (1, 16, 16, 15)

Comment: Run only the example code in the answer, and after that test the model by command model(tf.ones((1,16,16,15,1))) ...and verify that you get a result without error. If yes, your model is ready take in pictures having size (16,16,15,1) but remember if you have 10 pictures, then input size is (10,16,16,15,1), etc. By going through this principle, I think you will find a solution for the reason of the error you have met.